# Convert a local variable into a global variable in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a variable in asp.net which stores the value of a hidden field. I need that local variable to be accessible in another aspx page as I need to pass this value as a parameter to a wcf service url in kendo javascript. So I need the value in a global variable.

This is my code,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = hidden.Value;
}
```

What I want is,

```
public string month_name = s;
```

So that I can pass it in my wcf service url like this,

```
url:"http://<%=strWcfServer%>/WcfService1/Service1.svc/LoadProductCounts_Monthly‌​?month=<%=month_name%>"
```

Comment: If you want it to be accessible outside of the method, then by definition, it is not a local variable.   You need to create a non-local variable.

Comment: Why not just pass that value as a parameter where you need it?  It's a lot less fragile to your code base.  It also stops you from going down a slippery slope of designing an app that can only work for one person at a time.

Comment: But how can I assign a hiddenfiled value to a non-local variable?

Comment: @Arpita The same way you assign any value to any variable ever.

Comment: I need to pass this value as a parameter to a wcf service url in kendo javascript. So I need the value in a global variable.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class level variable that could be accessible from other methods in your `Page`, during the the processing of a request. At the end of the processing of the request this value will not be available from even another instance of the same `Page` class.

If you want to create a variable that could be accessible from other classes, I think that you should use the `Session` object.

```
Session["month_name"] = "the value you want to place here";
```

Then you could read this value from another class as simple as:

```
string month_name = (string)Session["month_name"];
```

**Update**

If you just need the current's month name you could just make use of this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

You don't have to make use of Session objects for situations like this.

Comment: Don't use static variables in a web app!  Use the session if you have to, but static variables mean one user at a time.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch I agree with that you say. I don't enforce Arpita to make use of static variables.  `"the value you want to place here"`. This could vary. I don't know what's the purpose of his variable and how often or under which conditions wants to update this value.

Comment: @Christos. I do not need current month. I have a hidden field which is retrieving the month name using onclick event in html td. I want to pass the month which was clicked in the wcf service url. I have the month in a hiddenfield. I just need to pass it to the wcf service url.

Comment: @Arpita Allright, I got it. So why you want this value be accessible from other classes? I assume that you have a service that you want to consume. You pass the needed parameters and you get the response. That's all. I don't see where you need to make use of this value that entails to save it somewhere and retrieve it later from there.

Comment: Yes, but the needed parameter for the service is not the same each time. It depends on which month the user clicks on. So I need to have the value of the month from user's click, I will pass it to the wcf service and then I will get the response for that particular month.

Comment: @Arpita It makes sense. The parameter will not be the same each time. Let's break it into this: 1) `I need to have the value of the month from user's click`. You could take this, as you already do, `<%=month_name%>`. 2) I will pass it to the wcf service and then I will get the response for that particular month.Of course you could pass it to your wcf service and then get the response. In the response, I suppose that you could have the information for the user that requested it, the month that user selected and the data you need to consume. Correct? Thanks

Comment: Yes. The only thing I am missing here is the retrieved value in a global variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69913/discussion-between-christos-and-arpita).

Answer (score 0):

The need for a global variable is almost always a sign of design problems, especially in a web application. That said, it can be done using either session variables (not technically global, but accessible from anywhere with some work) as Christos mentions, or with a static class.
The following was found with a web search: "asp global variable":

http://www.dotnetperls.com/global-variables-aspnet